# Issue Building Bootstrap dist not found

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, bootstrap-4

I'm running Ubuntu server and trying to build bootstrap.

Here is how I'm doing it:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git
$ cd bootstrap/
$ sudo npm -g install grunt-cli
$ npm install
$ sudo gem install bundler
$ bundle install
$ grunt dist
Warning: Task "dist" not found. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

**Gruntfile.js:**

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap's Gruntfile
 * https://getbootstrap.com
 * Copyright 2013-2017 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2013-2017 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  'use strict'

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    'saucelabs-qunit': {
      all: {
        options: {
          build: process.env.TRAVIS_JOB_ID,
          concurrency: 10,
          maxRetries: 3,
          maxPollRetries: 4,
          urls: ['http://localhost:3000/js/tests/index.html?hidepassed'],
          browsers: grunt.file.readYAML('build/sauce_browsers.yml')
        }
      }
    }
  })

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-saucelabs')
}
```

I'm following the exact documentation on the official site here:
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/build-tools/

They state on the site: "Our Gruntfile includes the following commands and tasks"

Clearly either I'm doing something wrong or reading the documentation incorrect but I feel I've been doing it correctly.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: The `Gruntfile.js` does not include a [registerTask](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#creating-tasks) named `dist` (nor any other registered Task) - hence the _Warning_. My guess it that their documentation is outdated. However, the projects `package.json` does include a `npm-script` named [dist](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/27a015ba15fa63d5c311c644c5c0efc2a2868fe7/package.json#L56). So perhaps `cd`'ing to the `bootstrap` directory and running `npm run dist` instead does the trick.

Comment: Latest bootstrap _build tools_ documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/build-tools/). `grunt` has been replaced with `npm-scripts`, so run `$ npm run dist` instead of `$ grunt dist`

Comment: That's good to know looks like I found the wrong documentation maybe I'll give the npm scripts a go this time.